# not fetching correct value of PLAY_LANG

Tags: java, scala, cookies, playframework, internationalization

```
@(implicit session:play.api.mvc.Session,lang:play.api.i18n.Lang)
```

`@lang.code` gives the PLAY_LANG cookie value of language of user,i stored `en-US` in cookie but it is returning `en-IN` `IN` is for India where i am. why it is taking this, how to remove it. and this is happening on a particular template, otherwise on other templates its work fine. 
**because of this my i18n is not working on template.**

I am using scala with play framework 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `@lang.code` returning the `en-IN`, it means its giving you `.defaultLang` in place of `.code`, may be you are using a variable of `lang` name also in your controller.and you confused the play so it is taking `.defaultLang`, which is returning `en-IN`.

make sure no variable name should be **lang** and the problem will be solved.